# Collision not detected by OnTriggerEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

So I'm trying to make a game about soccer. In this program, I'd created 2 objects called (in Hierarchy): `Ball` and `goal_line_1`. In this code, I'm trying to check if the ball collides with the goal line or not, and if it does collide, I will return (Lerp) the ball to the point in the middle `(0,0.3,0)`. But somehow when I drag the ball to the position that the ball collides with the goal line and then press play, the ball just stay there and don't return to the middle point.

```
public var smooth : float;

private var newPosition : Vector3;

function Awake ()
{
    newPosition = transform.position;
}

function OnTriggerEnter (ball : Collider)
{
    var positionA : Vector3 = new Vector3(0, 0.3, 0);

    newPosition = positionA;

    ball.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(ball.transform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you used `OnTriggerEnter()` function. This function is called when a collider **enters** a collision with another collider. What you do by dragging the ball into the line and then pressing play is actually skipping the 'Trigger Enter' event. There are three main events when it comes to collisions: TriggerEnter, TriggerStay and TriggerExit.

Although I'm not sure, if you change your function to [`OnTriggerStay()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html), you might get your function work. However for a safer testing method, I suggest you add a script to the ball so you can manually move it with your keyboard and see if the `OnTriggerEnter()` function works because by doing that, you will be simulating a more realistic situation (ball being kicked/moving towards the line rather than "suddenly existing" on the line).

Comment: Can you guide me how to script the ball ? Sorry I'm a newbie at Unity :D

Comment: Check this video: http://www.unity3dstudent.com/2010/07/beginner-b12-input-with-axes/

Comment: First I want to thank you for letting me know how to move objects.
But I seems like even though I've changed to OnTriggerEnter() the ball still doesn't lerp back to the middle point :'(

Comment: Are you sure you use `Lerp()` function correctly? Try to debug your code. What do you think your `Lerp()` function returns as a Vector3 and what it actually returns? Instead of changing the ball's position with lerp and assigning it back to its original variable, try to use a variable to store the lerp result in it and *then* assign it back to balls position variable.

Comment: But the lerp is an action,how can I store the result of that.But I think that I can try a simple code to change the ball position back to the middle point,but will you help me out with that please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2D, you need to change your `OnTriggerEnter` function to `OnTriggerEnter2D`.